# Builder pattern and dependency injection

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I'm working with the unit of work pattern to glue together my application logic. To create such a unit of work object I use the builder pattern.

But my unit of work classes need access to the service collection of the dependency injection container but as the builder pattern requires you to know how to new the object this won't work. That's why I wrote the `Build<T>` method on `MyUnitOfWork` which uses reflection and the service container to get the parameters to construct the unit of work.

I know that I could remove `MyUnitOfWorkConfiguration` from the unit of work constructors but in the code I'm using this `MyUnitOfWorkConfiguration` class is quite big and the change would mean I need to duplicate the properties into the builder and the unit of work class.

```
public class MyUnitOfWorkConfiguration
{
    public bool RunSynchronously { get; set; }
}
public class SpecialUnitOfWorkConfiguration : MyUnitOfWorkConfiguration
{
    public bool IgnoreSpecialError { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MyUnitOfWork<TConfiguration> where TConfiguration : MyUnitOfWorkConfiguration
{
    protected readonly TConfiguration Configuration;

    protected MyUnitOfWork(IMyDependencyIncectedService myDependencyIncectedService, TConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // do something with the myDependencyIncectedService
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected void ExecuteInner(Action action)
    {
        if (Configuration.RunSynchronously)
            action();
        else
            Task.Run(action);
    }
}
public class LoginUnitOfWork : MyUnitOfWork<MyUnitOfWorkConfiguration>
{
    public LoginUnitOfWork(IMyOtherDependencyIncectedService myOtherDependencyIncectedService, IMyDependencyIncectedService myDependencyIncectedService, MyUnitOfWorkConfiguration configuration)
        : base(myDependencyIncectedService, configuration)
    {
        // do something with the myOtherDependencyIncectedService
    }

    public void Login(string username, string password)
    {
        ExecuteInner(() =>
        {
            // do the login
        });
    }
}
public class SpecialUnitOfWork : MyUnitOfWork<SpecialUnitOfWorkConfiguration>
{
    public SpecialUnitOfWork(IMyDependencyIncectedService myDependencyIncectedService, SpecialUnitOfWorkConfiguration configuration) 
        : base(myDependencyIncectedService, configuration) { }

    public void Execute()
    {
        ExecuteInner(() =>
        {
            try { /* do special action */ }
            catch (SpecialException)
            {
                if (!Configuration.IgnoreSpecialError) throw;
            }
        });
    }
}

public abstract class MyUnitOfWorkBuilder<TConfiguration> where TConfiguration : MyUnitOfWorkConfiguration, new()
{
    protected readonly TConfiguration Configuration = new TConfiguration();

    public MyUnitOfWorkBuilder<TConfiguration> RunSynchronously()
    {
        Configuration.RunSynchronously = true;
        return this;
    }

    public T Build<T>() where T : MyUnitOfWork<TConfiguration>
    {
        var constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructors().First();
        var parameters = constructor.GetParameters();
        var parameterValues =
            parameters.Select(
                parameter =>
                    parameter.ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyUnitOfWorkConfiguration))
                        ? Configuration
                        : ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(parameter.ParameterType));

        return (T)constructor.Invoke(parameterValues.ToArray());
    }
}
public class MyUnitOfWorkBuilder : MyUnitOfWorkBuilder<MyUnitOfWorkConfiguration> { }
public class SpecialUnitOfWorkBuilder : MyUnitOfWorkBuilder<SpecialUnitOfWorkConfiguration>
{
    public SpecialUnitOfWorkBuilder IgnoreSpecialError()
    {
        Configuration.IgnoreSpecialError = true;
        return this;
    }
}

var loginUnitOfWork = new MyUnitOfWorkBuilder()
    .RunSynchronously()
    .Build<LoginUnitOfWork>();
loginUnitOfWork.Login("myUserName", "myPassword");

var specialUnitOfWork = new SpecialUnitOfWorkBuilder()
   .IgnoreSpecialError()
   .RunSynchronously()
   .Build<SpecialUnitOfWork>();
specialUnitOfWork.Execute();
```

Examples for such a `unit of work` are:

- ExitApplicationUnitOfWork (logs out users, cleans up, asks if the user is sure etc.)
- LoginUserUnitOfWork (logs the user in)
- LogoutUserUnitOfWork (logs the user out)
- BackupUnitOfWork (backs up stuff)

At the moment there are about 8 of those unit of work types and after the implementation of the new feature set there will be around 15.

My questions are

- Is what I do bad practice?
- Do I follow the rules of the `builder`, `unit of work` and `dependency injection` pattern? Or is what I did here something strange I came up with?^^
- Could I solve this better?

P.S.: If you have any other inputs to my code please just let me know.

Comment: There are a lot of `my`s. This does not look like real code.

Comment: @t3chb0t the "my" is just a replacement of the products name

Comment: @t3chb0t and the `SpecialUnitOfWork` is an example

Comment: It's really difficult to review it with such names. Everything is abstract and has no actuall meaning. Unfortunatelly this looks like an academic example from a book. It would be great if you could use more meaningfull names.

Comment: How many different configuration and 'unit of work' types do you have (or expect)?

Comment: @JanDotNet now there are 8. But after the implementation of the new featureset there will be around 15.

Comment: There are a few things that sting my eyes: `Build<T>()` with its generic-based code, new `*UnitOfWork` type construction through inheritance,  direct access to `ServiceLocator` instead of constructor injection, similarly `= new TConfiguration()` instead of injection... I tried to rewrite the code, but didn't come up with a working solution. I am not sure what are your real limitations (problem definition) vs things I can change. What is good about your code? Well, the fact that it prevents the type explosion. Meaning, it enforces DRY at the cost of code clarity.

Comment: Yes, certain things are bad practices. However, they seem to be least of the alternative evils. Subjective: I recommend you to *not listen to anyone blindly blaming the code without providing an alternative*. I'll wait for the constructive criticism -- an answer that has the complete code that does the same + is cleaner + is not much heavier.

Comment: * Correction: `Build<T>() with its generic-based code` --> `Build<T>() with its REFLECTION-based code`

Answer (score 1):

As t3chb0t mentioned in a comment, the code is hard to review because it contains only the the structural code without any functional stuff.

Maybe that is the reason that it looks a little bit over-engineered to me. I'll try it anyway.. however probably the review does not fit to your real code ;)

In my eyes, the builder has no functionality but providing a nice fluent API for initializing the configuration object and creating the UnitOfWork object. The second part requires the access to a service locator (with has actually nothing to do with dependency injection).

So, first of all I would drop the builder and create the configuration object manually (alternatively you could use the builder only for building the the configuration object and pass it to the unit of work in a separate step):

```
var config = new ConfigurationObjectA();
config.PropertyA = "Value";
...

var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWorkA(config, dependenyA, ....);
```

However, there is still the problem with the dependencies that must be injected manually. Depending on the DI Framework, you can use a factory for creating the UnitOfWorks with all it's dependencies. Ninject for example has an excellent [Extensions](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki) providing exactly that by creating a simple interface:

```
public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    UnitOfWorkA CreateUnitOfWorkA(ConfigurationA config);
    UnitOfWorkB CreateUnitOfWorkB(ConfigurationB config);
    ....
}
```

Just register the interface as factory and you can use it for creating the unit of work objects. If the unit of work has additional constructor dependencies (which have to be registered in the DI container of course), Ninject injects these dependencies automatically.

That solution looks a) simpler with b) less code and c) without using a service locator ;)

Comment: but I would need to write a factory method for every unit of work right? so I exchange the `reflection` and the `service locator` with an factory. Its just less flexible^^

Comment: and the builder pattern can't be dropped.. it's needed for all the default values and different configurations

Comment: You don't need to implement the interface - just define it and Ninject creates it's implementation "magically".

Comment: that sounds not to bad

Comment: but I'm using PRISM.. which doesn't want to relay on a specific dependency injection implementation.. as far as I remember

Comment: If you have configuration objects with different defaults, just create a class with methods for creating that default initialized objects. It is much simple to understand compared to generic builder with sub classes...

Comment: `just create a class with methods for creating that default initialized objects` => I think I will consider this.. as long as the "builder" class doesn't get to big

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to leave comments due to the amount of reputation I have, so I have to resort to leaving a post.

> Is what I do bad practice?

Yes. Service location is a well established anti-pattern. If you have to resort to using service location there is something wrong with the underlying design of your application.

Comment: I humbly recommend you to provide a complete example of a reworked version (since I myself was unable to come up with one that is *less complex*). It's not really helpful in this specific case to know *it's a bad practice* without knowing what the *best practice would look like*.